# PHP & MYSQL i dont recieve a error code but i just recieve the rest of my code

Tags: php, mysql

i dont understand what i am doing wrong and why its not displaying an error code but it displays the rest of my code after a specific word.

Code:

```
    <?php
    $errors = array();

$required = array(
'InvoiceFrom'   =>'This is required',
'InvoiceTo'     =>'This is required',
'InvoiceAddress'=>'This is required',
'ContactName'   =>'This is required',
'ContactNumber' =>'This is required',
'Email'         =>'This is required',
'PoNo'          =>'This is required',
'Details'       =>'This is required',
'InvoiceAmount' =>'This is required',
'Submitted'     =>'This is required',
'SubmittedBy'   =>'This is required',
);

if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
  foreach ($required as $field => $error)
    {
    $isEmpty = 0 == strlen(trim($_POST[$field]));

    if ($isEmpty) {
        $errors[] = $error;
    }
}

if ( ! filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors[] = 'Email must be a valid email address';
}

if ( ! preg_match('~^[0-9.]+$~i', $_POST['InvoiceAmount'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Invoice amount value is invalid';
}

if ( ! empty($errors))
{
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","FORM","form","form");

    $sql = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO
            table
        (InvoiceFrom, InvoiceTo, InvoiceAddress, ContactName, ContactNumber, Email, PoNo, Details, InvoiceAmount, Submitted, SubmittedBy )
            VALUES
        ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s','%s');",
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceFrom']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceTo']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceAddress']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ContactName']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ContactNumber']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PoNo']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Details']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceAmount']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Submitted']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SubmittedBy'])
    );

    $res = mysql_query($sql, $con);

    if ($res) {
        header('Location: http://example.org/success', true, 301);
        exit;
    }

    $errors[] = mysql_error($con);
}
 }
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php if (count($errors)): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
                <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <form method="post">
    </form>
</body>
```

What is outputed:

```
'This is required','InvoiceTo' =>'This is required','InvoiceAddress'=>'This is required','ContactName' =>'This is required','ContactNumber' =>'This is required','Email' =>'This is required','PoNo' =>'This is required','Details' =>'This is required','InvoiceAmount' =>'This is required','Submitted' =>'This is required','SubmittedBy' =>'This is required',); if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) { foreach ($required as $field => $error) { $isEmpty = 0 == strlen(trim($_POST[$field])); if ($isEmpty) { $errors[] = $error; } } if ( ! filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { $errors[] = 'Email must be a valid email address'; } if ( ! preg_match('~^[0-9.]+$~i', $_POST['InvoiceAmount'])) { $errors[] = 'Invoice amount value is invalid'; } if ( ! empty($errors)) { $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","FORM","form","form"); $sql = sprintf( "INSERT INTO table (InvoiceFrom, InvoiceTo, InvoiceAddress, ContactName, ContactNumber, Email, PoNo, Details, InvoiceAmount, Submitted, SubmittedBy ) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s','%s');", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceFrom']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceTo']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceAddress']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ContactName']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ContactNumber']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PoNo']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Details']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['InvoiceAmount']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Submitted']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SubmittedBy']) ); $res = mysql_query($sql, $con); if ($res) { header('Location: http://example.org/success', true, 301); exit; } $errors[] = mysql_error($con); } } include "ERROR.html" ?>
```

Could you please explain what i'm doing wrong and how i caould make it better?

Comment: is this a typo? `$isEmpty = 0 == strlen(trim($_POST[$field]));`

Comment: What do you mean by this code   $isEmpty = 0 == strlen(trim($_POST[$field]));

Comment: But thats not the issue the issue is when i've ran the form when it is outputted i recieve the rest of my code after :     <?php
    $errors = array();

$required = array(
'InvoiceFrom'   =>

then im outpuuter the rest of the code after that section of the code.

Comment: Yes, you can. In this case, `$isEmpty` will contain boolean TRUE or FALSE, depending on the result of the comparison. It's completely valid code.

Comment: @Jamie Sterling: How are you running this code? Which webserver (if any)?

Comment: This `$res = mysql_query($sql, $con);` by the way, should be `$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);` using `mysqli_` connections comes first. You are mixing APIs also. You can't do that. Your code needs a complete rewrite. Your DB connection => `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","FORM","form","form");`

Comment: That is valid code, albeit a little pointless in this case. That is not the issue here though. I ran your code exactly as is and it works just fine. Perhaps you haven't posted everything or there is something wrong with your server?

Comment: @Boreded You ran a mix of `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions and it worked? Hm... well well. `mysqli_` connection `mysqli_connect` with `mysql_real_escape_string` right. I doubt that very much.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That bit didn't run, commented them out. I am referring to the fact that structure of the code is fine and the problem is likely elsewhere. You are right there is also issues there that could be the cause.

Comment: @JamieSterling You're not getting errors because you're not checking for them. Here, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you'll see the errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Their is no errors showing.

Comment: Ok, well either way; you're mixing MySQL APIs, and you can't do that. Start by converting your entire code to use strictly `mysqli_*` functions and you'll be on your way to success.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok i converted the entire code into mysqi_* and im still recieving the same issue.

Comment: Have you passed DB connection to `mysqli_real_escape_string`? Update your question with what you're now using. `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` work differently you know. As for not getting any errors, I find that rather strange.